# Minimize auxiliary NSWindow to footer tab tray, like Apple Mail (Mac)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nstabview

I'm trying to implement the auxillary window minimize functionality when in fullscreen, like Apple Mail.

In fullscreen mode, on clicking compose, [the compose window appears in the foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1UgX.jpg).

And then clicking minimize [moves the compose window to the footer tab tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLm1y.jpg), instead of minimizing it to the Dock, where it would be out of sight.